# File input doesnt show up in $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have this input form field:

```
              <div class="inputContainer">
                <img src="images/3_randomfilm.jpeg" alt="image" width="100">
                <label for="radioEdit1" class="labelForm radioLabel">Afbeelding
                        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radioAfbeelding" id="radioEdit1" onclick="showEditInput('file')" checked />
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label for="radioEdit2" class="labelForm radioLabel">Video
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radioYoutube" id="radioEdit2" onclick="showEditInput('url')"/>
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                        <input type="file" id="fileEditInput" name="fileEditInput" class="input hidden" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/gif, image/jpeg">
                        <input type="url" id="urlEditInput" name="youtube_url" class="input hidden" value="">
              </div>
```

When I try to post this, everything posts except the fileEditInput. I just dont get it... Why does this not post?

```
 <input type="file" id="fileEditInput" name="fileEditInput" class="input hidden" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/gif, image/jpeg">
```

This is how I post it in PHP if you want to know:

```
$_POST['fileEditInput']
```

I tried giving it another name, but I just dont know how this can be wrong. Maybe I mistyped something but right now I cant just see it...

I hope you all can help me...

Comment: Where is the start of your form? I mean: What does your `<form>` tag look like? Perhaps you need [read these manual items](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)? They explain how it works. Note that files appear in `$_FILES`, not in `$_POST`.

Comment: This is what my form looks like
 <form action="edit.php" class="contactform" method="post" id="formEdit" enctype="multipart/form-data"> </form>

Comment: As mentioned above, you need to use $_FILES to access file data instead of $_POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [$_FILES](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) instead of $_POST

Files uploaded through a form will be in $_FILES and not in $_POST. The rest of the form data will be in $_POST.